# How do I install basemap on Kaggle? Can someone provide the code?

Tags: python, matplotlib-basemap, kaggle

I am trying to install higher resolution Basemap (basemap-data-hires)and the pip commands I am finding don't seem to work. Thanks!

OSError: Unable to open boundary dataset file. Only the 'crude' and  'low',
resolution datasets are installed by default.
If you are requesting an, 'intermediate', 'high' or 'full'
resolution dataset, you may need to download and install those
files separately with
`conda install basemap-data-hires`.

Error when running `!pip install basemap-data-hires`
Collecting basemap-data-hires
  Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError(': Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution',)': /simple/basemap-data-hires/
  Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError(': Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution',)': /simple/basemap-data-hires/
  Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError(': Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution',)': /simple/basemap-data-hires/
  Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError(': Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution',)': /simple/basemap-data-hires/
  Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError(': Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution',)': /simple/basemap-data-hires/
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement basemap-data-hires (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for basemap-data-hires

Comment: What have you tried? Simple `!pip install` inside the cell should work if you have internet turned on in kernel's settings.

Comment: !pip install basemap-data-hires, !pip install basemap. I am trying to get the high resolution maps which appears to require the basemap-data-hires version.

Comment: And the error messages returned after this operation? __Always__ include details about your problem, as it stand it's too vague for anyone to help you.

Answer (score 0):

In the kernel:

1) Setting (at the right bottom of the kernel): 
Turn the internet "ON"

2) In the kernel:

```
!pip install basemap-data-hires
```